# How to connect to Azure MySQL sever from Azure VM via private endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I created a private endpoint to an Azure SQL server and want to connect to it from a VM in the same virtual network. The private endpoint gives me a private IP address `10.0.0.4`.

However, when I try to connect to the server on a VM using `mysqlsh`, it gives the the following error:

```
MySQL Error 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.0.4' (110)
```

Are there steps that I've missed other than creating the private endpoint (E.g. some kind of firewall configuration)? My impression was that once I have the private endpoint, I could access the server on my VMs via the private IP address.

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-privatelink-portal?

Comment: Could you please tell me if you can ping private IP in your VM?